# Getting nested item on onClick of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have row_item.xml  with nestem  LinearLayout and multiple ImageViews. It generates 2 x 2 image grid in each row of ListView. On onClick aI want to know on which Image item user has clicked.

In onClick method I have tried to see which item is actually coming using item.getClass() and it shows LinearLayout. I am sure this will be top level layout in row Item. Here is my row item skeleton layout. I am looking for some generic approach where in I can get hold of clicked item at any depth.

```
<LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout>
           <ImageView> </ImageView>
           <ImageView> </ImageView>
       </LinearLayout>         

       <LinearLayout>
           <ImageView> </ImageView>
           <ImageView> </ImageView>
       </LinearLayout>         
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image views clickable by setting appropriate options in xml where you declare your listView. And then just add onclickListeners to your imageViews.
For me solution that worked was setting:

```
clickable
focusable
focusableInTouchMode
```

to **true**. If you have this done, you can in your adapter getView/bindView setonClickListeners to your imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

For each ImageView add the following:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="myOnClickFunction"
```

and add code like:

```
public void myOnClickFunction(final View imageView) {
    // imageView.getId() - actual image view id.
}
```